# Using XPATH previous:: more like an array

Tags: xpath

I've got XML like this

```
<root>
  ...
  <a>
  <a>
  <a>
  <c>
...
```

It's very flat with LOTS of A elements and a few C elements. The A elements are sensor data and the last reading is bogus, I need the one before. So I'd like to use the C elements as a marker and each of A elements 2 before each C. So I'm trying out an XPATH like:

```
/root/c/preceding-sibling::a
```

but I'm getting all previous A elements, I was hoping for something a bit more direct such as:

```
/root/c/preceeding-sibling[-2]
```

which would just grab the 2nd sibling before C (no matter the type) I guess I'm asking for array like functionality on an XPATH so what ever I match I can ask for "the second element before that"

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

> just grab the 2nd sibling before C (no matter the type)

with the XPath expression

```
/root/c/preceding-sibling::*[2]
```

The node count for `preceding-sibling::` is going backwards. The node with the index `[1]` is the node before `c` and the node with the index `[2]` is the node before this - which is

> the second element before that